# WebSync Publish ClientId become zero

Tags: javascript, c#, websync

There is an issue when I pass Client.clientId in the [Websync publish](https://docs.frozenmountain.com/websync4/#class=websync-getting-started-basic-concepts-30_publishing) method, the clientId sometimes become all zero when catch by the [OnReceive](https://docs.frozenmountain.com/websync4/#class=WebSync.Javascript.fm.websync.subscribeReceiveArgs) event from the client side.

May I know why sometimes the clientId value is successfully sent via the channel but most often the clientId value is somehow become all zero like 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000.

Below is my code

**Subscribe**

```js
var client = new fm.websync.client('http://localhost:12345/websync');

client.connect
({
    onSuccess: function (e) {
        $('#connectionStat').val('Successfully connected');
    },
    onFailure: function (e) {
        $('#connectionStat').val('Failed to be connected');
    },
    onStreamFailure: function (e) {
        $('#connectionStat').val('Failed to be connected on stream');
    }
});

client.subscribe({
    channel: '/testService/clientId',
    onSuccess: function (e) {

    },
    onFailure: function (e) {

    },
    onReceive: function (e) {
        alert(e.getData());
    }
});
```

**Publish**

```
Client client = new Client("http://localhost:12345/websync");
client.Connect(new ConnectArgs
{
       OnSuccess = (e) =>
       {
          Debug.WriteLine("Successfully connected [OnSuccess]");
       },
       OnFailure = (e) =>
       {
           Debug.WriteLine("Failed in connected [OnFailure]");
       },
       OnComplete = (e) =>
       {
           Debug.WriteLine("Successfully connected [OnComplete]");
        },
        OnStreamFailure = (e) =>
        {
           Debug.WriteLine("Failed connected [OnStreamFailure]");
        }
});   

client.Publish(new PublishArgs("/testService/clientId", Json.Serialize(client.ClientId))
{
       OnSuccess = (e) =>
       {
           Debug.WriteLine("Successfully published client id [OnSuccess] = " + client.ClientId.ToString());
       },
       OnComplete = (e) =>
       {
           Debug.WriteLine("Successfully published [OnComplete]");
       },
       OnFailure = (e) =>
       {
           Debug.WriteLine("Failed to publish [OnFailure]");
       },
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Wait to `Publish` until after `Connect` has completed successfully. The client's ID is generated by the server, and when `Publish` is called, there's a chance the `Connect` operation hasn't completed yet.

The easiest thing to do is move the `Publish` call into the `OnSuccess` callback of `Connect`.